# figure.add_subplot() vs pyplot.subplot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

What is the difference between `add_subplot()` and `subplot()`? They both seem to add a subplot if one isn't there. I looked at the documentation but I couldn't make out the difference. Is it just for making future code more flexible?

For example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

vs

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(111)
```

from matplotlib tutorials.

Answer (score 13):

If you need a reference to `ax` for later use:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

gives you one while with:

```
plt.subplot(111)
```

you would need to do something like:

```
ax = plt.gca()
```

Likewise, if want to manipulate the figure later:

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

gives you a reference right away instead of:

```
fig = plt.gcf()
```

Getting explicit references is even more useful if you work with multiple subplots of figures. Compare:

```
figures = [plt.figure() for _ in range(5)]
```

with:

```
figures = []
for _ in range(5):
    plt.figure()
    figures.append(plt.gcf())
```

Comment: Does this explanation help?

Comment: that's not true. `plt.subplot(111)` returns a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` object, exactly as add_subplot, so you can do `ax=plt.subplot(111)`

Answer (score 6):

`pyplot.subplot` is wrapper of `Figure.add_subplot` with a difference in behavior.
Creating a subplot with `pyplot.subplot` will delete any pre-existing subplot that overlaps with it beyond sharing a boundary. 
If you do not want this behavior, use the `Figure.add_subplot` method or the `pyplot.axes` function instead. [More](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html)

Answer (score 4):

It's just like what [Matplotlib document](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) says, which has also been mentioned in [@afruzan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57855482/17797688).

> `matplotlib.pyplot.subplot`: Creating a new Axes will **delete any pre-existing Axes that overlaps with it** beyond sharing a boundary. If you do not want this behavior, use the `Figure.add_subplot` method or the `pyplot.axes` function instead.

To make it more clear, here is an illustration:

- Use `Figure.add_subplot`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(131, facecolor='red')
fig.add_subplot(132, facecolor='green')
fig.add_subplot(133, facecolor='blue')
fig.add_subplot(231, facecolor='cyan')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- Use `pyplot.subplot`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(131, facecolor='red')
fig.add_subplot(132, facecolor='green')
fig.add_subplot(133, facecolor='blue')
plt.subplot(231, facecolor='cyan') # overlap with subplot generated by fig.add_subplot(131, facecolor='red'), so subplot generated by fig.add_subplot(131, facecolor='red') will be removed
plt.show()
```

[image]