# How to plot two time series data with different time frequency on same axis in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have 2 time series data.

1. Daily stock return of company ABC
2. Annual revenue of ABC

I want to plot those 2 series on a same figure (same x-axis) so that I can get a visual sense that how does those two data correlated with each other as shown in the graph below. How can I achieve that in python with pandas and matplotlib?

[image]

Comment: bar plot does not play well with time series, especially when plot together with another time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Made up Stock price data
stock_price = np.random.random_sample(size=100)*20+np.exp(0.05*np.arange(100))
stock_price_df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2023',periods=len(stock_price)), 'stock price':stock_price})
stock_price_df = stock_price_df.set_index('dates')

# Made up revenue data
revenue = np.random.random_sample(size=100)*20+np.exp(0.02*np.arange(100))
revenue_df= pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2023',periods=len(revenue)), 'revenue': revenue})
revenue_df = revenue_df.set_index('dates')
revenue_df_agg = revenue_df.resample('Y').mean().reset_index()

# Plot two of them together
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(pd.to_datetime(revenue_df_agg['dates'].dt.year, format='%Y'), revenue_df_agg['revenue'], width=200)
ax.set_ylabel('Revenue')
ax1 = ax.twinx()
s = stock_price_df['stock price'].plot(ax = ax1, style = '-r')
ax1.set_ylabel('Stock price')
ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('r')
ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('r')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='r')
plt.savefig('collage-2.png')
plt.show()
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Thank you plasmon, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Just one quick question: why we are using subplots there? I thought that is only used when you need to plot several different figures in a chart. Is there a more straight-forward way of achieving this?

Comment: I was using subplots because without any arguments, it defaults to 1 row and 1 col. So it creates one axes which I am used to. I hope that helps.

Comment: Got it. I'm still learning it. Do gcf() & gca() do the same job as subplots() in terms of getting the object (figure and axes)?

Comment: If this answer answers your questions. please mark as "accepted". https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Done. Could you please answer the above question. Thank you very much!

Comment: gcf() stands for get current figure object and gca() stands for get current axis object. You can get a figure object (generally assigned as 'fig') and then add a subplot using (add_subplot) and assign it to 'ax'. There are many ways to plot in matplotlab. see here for more details explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442283/figure-add-subplot-vs-pyplot-subplot. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I have read it. If I understand correctly, the 3 "fig" object get from plt.figure(),  subplot(), and gcf() are the same, right?

Comment: Much appreciated!